# Xcode build error: pngcrush caught libpng error

Tags: xcode, libpng

I have been getting this error on and off for the longest time, and no suggestions have worked so far. I have tried resaving and replacing the images, but it simply has not worked

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, when I checked in Build Phases, that these images were duplicated. And for whatever reason, this sometimes turned out to cause an issue. Once I removed the duplicates, all was fixed!